# Find duplicate value with Vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have a form to enter values, to submit to a sheet.

To avoid duplicate data I use the vlookup function to search the range of values on the sheet and display a message if the value already exists.

My code works when I enter a value that is already on the data sheet.

When I enter a new value it gives the following error:

> Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

I think it has something to do with the vlookup #N/A output.

```
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Set MyWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

If Me.tbx_DINumber.Value <> Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.tbx_DINumber.Value, MyWorksheet.Range("D3:D100"), 1, False Then

    .Cells(myFirstBlankRow, 4) = Me.tbx_DINumber.Value

Else

If Me.tbx_DINumber.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.tbx_DINumber.Value, MyWorksheet.Range("D3:D100"), 1, False) Then MsgBox "DI NUMBER ALREADY EXISTS IN THE DATABASE!"
```

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share a ***specific* problem** after trying to solve it on their own. Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge!) and see "[ask]", and also the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.  If you have a *specific* problem with a certain section of your code, you can [edit] your post to share an **[mcve]** as well as sample data and some background info.  Here are some  [tips](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the site's top user. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Me.tbx_DINumber.Value <> Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.tbx_DINumber.Value, MyWorksheet.Range("D3:D100"), 1, False) Then

should be

if IsError(Application..VLookup(Me.tbx_DINumber.Value, MyWorksheet.Range("D3:D100"), 1, False)) Then

Comment: This fix has worked for the initial If statement but now I am getting the same error for the Else If Statement.

Comment: you need to replace the elseif with a simple else. Either there's a match or there isn't. If there's no match the if iserror... line is true, else there's no match